# Import geojson data to a leaflet map origanated from overpass turbo

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am not a native English speaker so please don't mind the mistakes ;)

I want to make a map where you can find farm shops and milk vending machines for people that want to support their local farmers. I found out that these things can be found in the OSM data with the tags `shop=farm` and `amenity=vending_machine selling:milk`. With that information you can easily crate a query on http://overpass-turbo.eu and export it as a JSON file. I used "osmtogeojson" to convert this Data to GeoJSON and stored a small test sample as "test.geojson" in my main folder. I also 
downloaded `leaflet.ajax.min.js` and put it in my main folder. Now I want to import this local GeoJSON file into a Leaflet map. So here is my situation:

My head area looks like this: (pretty much everything is a copy from the tutorials on leafletjs.com and Stack Overflow)

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />
<script src="/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-07I2e+7D8p6he1SIM+1twR5TIrhUQn9+I6yjqD53JQjFiMf8EtC93ty0/5vJTZGF8aAocvHYNEDJajGdNx1IsQ==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-A7vV8IFfih/D732iSSKi20u/ooOfj/AGehOKq0f4vLT1Zr2Y+RX7C+w8A1gaSasGtRUZpF/NZgzSAu4/Gc41Lg==" crossorigin=""></script>
```

An this is (the important part of) the JavaScript:

```js
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("test.geojson");
geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
```

EDIT:Here is a live demo: https://stefang.cepheus.uberspace.de/farmshops/
you can find my /test.geojson file there too.

Does anyone know what went wrong here?

*Less* important JS part (imported from comments on behalf of OP):

```js
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([49.013, 8.40], 10);
L.tileLayer('api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?acc‌​ess_token=<TOKEN>', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>; contributors, ' + '<a href="creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</…;, ' + 'Imagery © <a href="mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>';,
  id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you say "There are no errors", do you mean you have checked your browser console? Your scripts loading order is strange.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. I have to say no I didn't.  I thought every error causes an error dialog. But the browser console helps me a lot, I think I have to initalize the object first. The error is: 
TypeError: geojsonLayer is undefined

Comment: I admit I would have expected another error before that one: "L is undefined" or something similar, due to loading Leaflet.ajax plugin before Leaflet?

Comment: No I defined L earlier, I left it out of the post to keep it small:
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([49.013, 8.40], 10);
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
maxZoom: 18,
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
'<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(mymap);

Comment: There may be some issue in your GeoJSON data, then. At this stage, it might be difficult to help you further without a live test case (e.g. on JSFiddle, Plunker, JSBin, etc.) that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Here is a live demo: https://stefang.cepheus.uberspace.de/farmshops/
this is my geojson file: view-source:https://stefang.cepheus.uberspace.de/farmshops/test.geojson
Thank you for your help so far :) I try to understand the structure of the geojson format in the meantime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You do not have the expected `L is not defined` error because your `<script>` src attribute is erroneous (your extra leading slash `/` makes the browser try to access the file at `https://stefang.cepheus.uberspace.de/leaflet.ajax.min.js`, whereas it is placed at `https://stefang.cepheus.uberspace.de/farmshops/leaflet.ajax.min.js`)

2) Once this is corrected, the `L is not defined` error correctly appears. You have to place the `<script>` tag for Leaflet-ajax plugin **after** the one for Leaflet.

3) The `TypeError: geojsonLayer is undefined` error is due to your line`geojsonLayer.addTo(map)` being actually placed *before* `var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("test.geojson")` You have to put it **after** the variable assignment.

Once these 3 errors are corrected, your GeoJSON file seems to be imported and rendered correctly.

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/OwyfvvoaseLhhCyleN4n?p=preview

Comment: Wow thank you very much, this is a great answer, that solves all my problems! Great work and a great base to work further into this topic :)

Comment: Yw. Please note that the SO way to thank people is also to _accept_ the answer. Once you have more _reputation_, you will also have the ability to _up/down-vote_.